# How to display all images from a folder to web (flask web app)

Tags: python, flask

I am very new here and very new to the world of programming so bear with me.

I want to make a very simple flask web app with python.

I have the flaskapp.py in which i have the routes to my index.html and the images.html

I have a "photos" folder in the "static" folder with hundrends of jpg files inside.

I want the images.html to display all the jpg files which are in the photos folder.
How can i do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

index.html

```
 {% for img in images %}
     <img src=static/photo/{{ img }}>
 {% endfor %}
```

app.py

```
images = os.listdir(path='static/photo/')


@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('index.html', images=images)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can set the `src` parameter of the images that you insert on the `index.html` file as the absolute path to each one of the `.jpg` files. So every `img` tag inside the HTML refers to a specific path to the static images folder.